# FOSRestBundle: How to configure a fallback format

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

My goal is to have a default json output when the user agent is set to anything else than json or xml. I have configured FOSRestBundle 1.1.0 as follows:

```
fos_rest:
format_listener: true
param_fetcher_listener: true
view:
    default_engine: php
    formats:
        json: true
        xml: true
    templating_formats:
        html: false
    view_response_listener: force
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
```

This works. Now I added the following configuration:

```
format_listener:
    rules:
        - { fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false, priorities: ['xml', 'json'] }
```

As soon as I do that, I can no longer switch between formats by either appending `?_format=json` or `?_format=xml` and also the Accept header seems to be ignored, it always uses whatever I specify in the accept header.

How to configure FOSRestBundle so that it accepts json or XML via Parameter/HTTP Request header *and* falls back to json if the format accepted by the browser is HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FOSRestBundle Docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#format-listener):

> Note that if _format is matched inside the route, then a virtual Accept header setting is added with a q setting one lower than the lowest Accept header, meaning that format is checked for a match in the priorities last. If prefer_extension is set to true then the virtual Accept header will be one higher than the highest q causing the extension to be checked first. Setting priorities to a non empty array enables Accept header negotiations.

Also, I noticed that in the `rules` section, you are missing the `path` option.  So the application doesn't know which path to apply the rules to.

Take a look at the docs I linked to above, it has an example.

Comment: While I have read the documentation several times before, this answer led me to the correct solution. A rule is _not_ needed to make this work; instead, all I was missing was a default format for the route, which I've set to JSON.